# husky pre commit error the --no-stash option has been renamed to --no-reset

Tags: node.js, git, commit, pre-commit-hook, husky

I am having an issue when making a commit and using Husky in my project.

This is the error I get when I make a commit such as `git commit -m "feat: test commit"`

```sh
me@my-laptop whatever % git commit -m "feat: test commit" 
⚠ The `--no-stash` option has been renamed to `--no-reset`.

husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)
```

The version of Husky I am using is the 7.0.4 and this is the pre-commit hook file

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npx lint-staged
npx pretty-quick --staged
```

Any Idea of what could be the issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the issue I was having was a malformed `package.json` (it had an extra comma).

This led the linter to fail, although no errors about it appear in the output.

Once I removed the extra comma, I was able to commit again :)

Answer (score 0):

This should come from [`okonet/lint-staged`](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged), which mentions the renaming in [PR 1023](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged/pull/1023)

> This experimental rewrite no longer uses git stashing, thus increasing performance.
>
> It also renames the `--no-stash` option to `--no-reset`, but leaves the former as a hidden option (with warning) for backwards compatibility.

It seems to be a warning, not a blocking issue.

Try and call it with the option explicitly added:

```
npx lint-staged --noreset=false
```

Comment: Hey @VonC  it seems like the issue was due to a malformed package.json. I added a solution explaining it. However, thank you for your answer :)

Comment: @reymon359 Yes, I left a comment on your answer acknowledging your findings.